# How can I loop through a number of models and get a total of the models with the same parameters?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

Sorry if the title was confusing, not sure how to word it.

Basically I have a number of models with parameters (lets say Date, Quantity, Trans ID, and Price). My question is how can I loop through all of the models and add up a total row for the the ones that share the same Date and Trans ID.

For example:

All Models:
      Date                  Quantity            Trans ID        Price
01/12/2014                    5                 ABC123        10.00

01/12/2014                    7                 ABC123        15.00
01/21/2014                    6                  XYZ321        11.90

Results: (total row for models with same date and Trans ID)
      Date                  Quantity            Trans ID        Price
01/12/2014                    5                 ABC123        10.00

01/12/2014                    7                 ABC123        15.00
                                     12                                     25.00
01/21/2014                    6                  XYZ321        11.90

I've tried using a LINQ .ForEach because that's how I've gotten totals before, but it's always been just adding up all of the values. I've never had a case where I need to only add certain ones based on a condition.

Any ideas?

BTW: I'm using MVC .net 3.5 so anything in 4 won't work :(

Comment: This question appears to be tightly tied to the display format. How is it being displayed? In any case, `myModels.GroupBy(x => new { x.Date, x.TransID }).Where(x => x.Count() > 1)` might be part of the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`GroupBy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb534501(v=vs.90).aspx) and [`Sum`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.linq.enumerable.sum(v=vs.90).aspx) are at the heart of what you need. Here's how you might get the list you want:

```
IEnumerable<MyModel> GetGroupedModels(IEnumerable<MyModel> myModels)
{
    foreach (var group in myModels.GroupBy(x => new { x.Date, x.TransID }))
    {
        foreach (var item in group)
            yield return item;
        if (group.Count() > 1)
            yield return new MyModel { Quantity = group.Sum(x => x.Quantity), Price = group.Sum(x => x.Price) };
    }
}
```

Note that this isn't the most efficient way to do the calculations, but it has good readability and conciseness (which are usually more important than speed).

Answer (score 0):

I'm just guessing here, but I think there's also a `LINQ.Where` which you could use after your `ForEach` to add your condition.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to simply compute the totals, you can try this query:

```
models
      .GroupBy(model => new { model.Date, model.TransId })
      .Select(grouped => new { grouped.Key, TotalQuantity = grouped.Sum(model => model.Quantity) });
```

In the end you'll have a list of "Date, TransId, TotalQuantity" items which you can display in whatever format makes sense for your application.

You can also use some of the other GroupBy overloads if you need to get more data into the grouping.

Answer (score -1):

```
int sum = 0;

Foreach(var example in Model modelName)
{
    if(modelName.quantity >= 7)
    {
        sum += modelName.Price;
    } 
}
```

I believe it could be done like above without too much trouble if I am understanding your question correctly.